# How to exclude data in mySQL string?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

it's just an example, my real tables are much larger and more complicated.

```
CREATE TABLE Apples (
    Id1,
    Name,
    Id2,
)

CREATE TABLE Colors (
    Id2,
    ColorName
)
```

I want to include all apples instead of the green variety of ID1 = 3 (lets lay called Boscop)

How to write the WHERE clause to exclude green Boscop?

I think it's easy but for the moment I have no idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the sample data and expected output.

Comment: `SELECT t1.name, t2.color FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2 WHERE (t1.name, t2.color) != ('Boscop', 'green')`?

Comment: What is the JOIN criteria between Apples and Colors? Is `Id1` the PK for an Apple or an FK to a Color?

Comment: I've updated my SQL code.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from apples a
where a.id1 = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from colors c
                  where a.id2 = c.id2 and c.color = 'green'
                 );
```